# List all the check-ins done by a user in Rational Team concert

Tags: version-control, rtc, rational-team-concert

How can I get the list of all the check-ins done by a user on a stream in Rational Team concert?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click on Source Control (in a project area of the Team Artifacts view), and [click `Search/change sets`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.concert.dotnet.doc/topics/t_searching_for_change_sets.html&scope=null).

You can then select the Creator you want, and you can refine the list of change sets per location (stream, workspace, baseline, ...) and per component.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/docs/source-control/faq/images/search_dialog.png]

You can [access that search also from your own Pending Changes view](https://jazz.net/library/article/126#I_discarded_a_change_set_I_was_working_on_but_I_really_need_it_back_again._How_can_I_find_it):

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/docs/source-control/faq/images/search_menu.png]

Comment: @AshwaniK I suppose with `lscm changeset locate`: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/157597/how-to-use-lscm-changeset-locate